# Rendering stringified JSON data into table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, function

I'm trying to display `all document Names` from a local JSON file. When I try to render the data it comes up as `undefined.` However, in the console I'm able to see the data all right.

As far as I can tell my for loop *looks* fine, so I'm wondering if the source of the problem is with `"Titles": obj.File.Name`. Other than that, I'm not sure.

---

#### JS file:

```
loadTableData() {
    let tableRes = redactedName.d.results.filter(function(val) { 
      return (val.FileLeafRef.trim().length > 0);
    }).map(function(obj) {

      return {
        // "FileName": obj.FileLeafRef,
        // "Path": obj.EncodedAbsUrl,
        "Titles": obj.File.Name
        }
      });

    let allTitles = tableRes;

    for (var i = 0; i < allTitles.length; i++) {
      let tr = $("<tr/>");
        $(tr).append("<td>" + allTitles.Name + "</td>");
        $("#km-table-id").append(tr)
    };
}
```

---

#### JSON snippet

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {
        "__metadata": {
          ...
        },
        "File": {
          "__metadata": {
            ...
          },
          "Name": "Guide to Product IDs.docx" <---------------------------
        },
        "FileLeafRef": "Guide to Product IDs.docx",
        "ResourceType": {
          ...
          },
          "results": [
            {
              ...
            }
          ]
        },
        "EncodedAbsUrl": [redacted]
      },
...
...
```

---

This is a sample of what I'm seeing in the console:

```
(491) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
[0 … 99]
0: {Titles: "Guide to Product IDs.docx"}
1: {Titles: "Template 1.docx"}
```

Comment: It should be `allTitles.Titles` in your for loop instead of `allTitles.Name`

Comment: Print `allTitles` in console and post the output in the question.

Comment: Hey Prerak, I changed it to allTitles.Titles but unfortunately the table rows still read as 'undefined.' Also, I edited my question with the console output.

Comment: You forgot the index of `allTitles` array. It should be `allTitles[i].Titles`.

Comment: Yep that was the problem. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Hey @PrerakSola, if you post your answer then I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an array, so you need to access each of its element using the index. Also, in `map`, you return the `Titles` property. So it should be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allTitles.length; i++) {
    let tr = $("<tr/>");
    $(tr).append("<td>" + allTitles[i].Titles + "</td>"); //Change in this line
    $("#km-table-id").append(tr)
};
```